# Conversion error while converting float to varchar in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
 SELECT
     (CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), 
      (select SUM(TransactionAmount) as saleamount 
       from ProductSaleInformation 
       where StoreCode = 1 
         and RegionCode = 1 
         and BillDate Between '2015-06-01' and '2015-10-31') - 
      (select SUM(TransactionAmount) as saleamount 
       from ProductSaleInformation 
       where StoreCode = 1 
         and RegionCode = 1 
         and BillDate Between '2015-01-01' and '2015-05-31')) / 
      (select SUM(TransactionAmount) as saleamount 
       from ProductSaleInformation 
       where StoreCode = 1 
         and RegionCode = 1 
         and BillDate Between '2015-01-01' and '2015-05-31') + '%') AS SALESGROWTH
```

Need help to convert the float to varchar

Comment: Could you edit this question to provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? All this code may not be necessary to solve your problem.

Comment: Please post the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Your query has an order of operation/logic error in it.

You are dividing a `VARCHAR` by a `FLOAT` due to an improperly placed parenthesis, I suspect you mean to do all the math first and finally convert the result to a `VARCHAR` to perform the string concatenation operation (adding a percent sign).

Also, you have no code formatting/indenting which would make this error **much** easier to see.

Try this corrected version:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),
            (
                select SUM(TransactionAmount) as saleamount
                from ProductSaleInformation
                where StoreCode=1 and RegionCode=1
                    AND BillDate Between '2015-06-01' AND '2015-10-31'
             ) -  (
                select SUM(TransactionAmount) as saleamount
                from ProductSaleInformation
                where StoreCode=1 and RegionCode=1
                    AND BillDate Between '2015-01-01' AND '2015-05-31'
            ) / (
                select SUM(TransactionAmount) as saleamount
                from ProductSaleInformation
                where StoreCode=1 and RegionCode=1
                    AND BillDate Between '2015-01-01' AND '2015-05-31'
            )) + '%' AS SALESGROWTH
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert `float` to `varchar`, you can use `CONVERT` or `CAST` function. Like this:

```
DECLARE @float FLOAT = 1.2
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @float)
SELECT CAST(@float AS VARCHAR(20))
```